# Moved Windows to Folder for better organisation, code behind won't work now

Tags: c#, wpf

Tried to move all my Windows to a folder called Views within Visual Studio for better organisation. But now I'm getting errors on Click events:

> Error    2   'JamSnapsWPF.Views.Main' does not contain a definition for 'addlogin_Click' and no extension method 'addlogin_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'JamSnapsWPF.Views.Main' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Martyn Ball\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\JamSnapsWPF\JamSnapsWPF\Views\Main.xaml  226 79  JamSnapsWPF

Here is the line which the error originates from:

```
<Button Name="addlogin" Click="addlogin_Click">
```

I have updated the Windows Class so that it references the code behind for that window:

```
<Window x:Class="JamSnapsWPF.Views.Main"
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you organize your files into folders inside Visual Studio, that doesn't automatically change the namespaces in any of your files.

Check your code-behind files to see what the namespace is. It should be the same namespace referenced at the top of your XAML files.

For example, I created an empty solution with one `Window`. I created a "Views" folder and moved the file into it. The code-behind moved too. But neither file references the "Views" folder in them anywhere. They still look like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()

        ...
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ... >
    ...
</Window>
```

Either change the namespace in your XAML back, or change the code-behind file to match it:

```
namespace WpfApplication2.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()

        ...
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        ... >
    ...
</Window>
```